# Batei Dinim in an Unrighteous Generation

Tags: halacha

The Torah says that all we have are the judges in our days (Rashi Dvarim 17:9). In a generation where the people, including the judges, have succumbed to idolotary, can a person still go to one of these judges? Or would he have nothing except the Shulchan Aruch and halachic literature? If a person wants to convert and can see that the judges are idolotars and are practicing necromancy while he is with them, would he be entitled to convert under one since there is no one else he/she can find, or be forced to continue searching and potentially not convert? This seems reasonable, as throughout the Tanach, the people of Israel were sinning these kinds of sins unless they had one of the righteous kings. Even after 40 years with Moses, he said, "You people have been sinners against H' for as long as I've known you"
Thank you

Comment: Lichorah this can never happen, ki lo sishakach mipi zaro

Comment: Sorry, can you put that all in English please?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Deuteronomy.31.21?lang=bi, כי לא תשכח מפי זרעו FOR IT SHALL NOT BE FORGOTTEN OUT OF THE MOUTHS OF THEIR SEED — This is an assurance to Israel that the Torah in which this song is contained will never be entirely forgotten by their descendants (Shabbat 138b).